# Free or cheap IDE with syntax support for Smarty or similar template system

Tags: php, ide, smarty

I'm starting to build a website where I want to use Smarty or a similar templating system to separate PHP logic and HTML structure. Smarty's caching support doesn't hurt either.

(Don't tell me that PHP is a templating language already -- I know it can easily be used like that, but I like the conceptual separation).

At the same time I want to move up from Dreamweaver as an IDE. I was happy when I saw that NetBeans has a Smarty plugin, but now that I've tried using it for a while, the support seems to be nothing more than keyword highlighting -- it doesn't match `{if}` with `{/if}` or check Smarty syntax, and on the other hand it seems to turn of some of the HTML autocompletions.

Is there anything out there with more complete coverage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) by jetbrains. Try it out.

Comment: I really like PhpStorm -- but it's not free *(see first word of the title of the question ;-) )*

Comment: Well, it's not prohibitively expensive, either. I'll amend the title...

Comment: If you use it in a classroom it's free...

Comment: Tried the demo version, and it does seem to do what I want. It also figures out mootools classes on the Javascript side. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Twig](http://www.twig-project.org) (which I like better than Smarty - although i still prefer self-restraint+plain php) most IDE's that support Django templating should work with it since the syntax is nearly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I use smarty-mode for emacs, wich provides syntax highlighting for smarty templates.